# ClickHandler on an existing element in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have an HTML document. In that document, there is an element (like button, div, a) with an ID. I know I can use:

```
Document.get().getElementById("id");
```

to find the required element in the HTML file. How can I add a Click handler to it? ClickHandlers only seem to be available on the Button class.

Thanks

Comment: Two options are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768961/adding-a-click-handler-for-an-html-element/2769295#2769295

Comment: This seems rather expensive to my taste. The solution below is more efficient. Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're trying to add a `ClickHandler` to a `<button>`, you can do that with [`Button.wrap()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html#wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)).

For an `<a>` yo can use [`Anchor.wrap()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html#wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)) (`Anchor`s only have `ClickListener`s, not `ClickHandler`s...yet)

For a `<div>` you can use [`Label.wrap()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Label.html#wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)) (`Label`s are just `<div>`s).

Comment: Perfect! You've been super helpful. I kept trying to do like new Button(Element element). Thanks!

Comment: Also you can use HTML.wrap() for anything that doesn't match the Button/Anchor/Label grouping Jason mentioned

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion :
Try learning how to use UiBinder (added in GWT 2.0).

In your case, you could have done :

**yourView.ui.xml**

```
...
<g:Button ui:field="btnName" />
...
```

**yourView.java**

```
public class yourView extends Composite {
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<LayoutPanel, yourView> {}
    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

    @UiField Button btnName;

    public yourView() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @UiHandler("btnName")
    void handleClick(ClickEvent e) {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```

With "@UiHandler" you can add any handler the widget can support (implement Has****Handler). Adding other element to that structure is easy and FAST and you can add any kind of handler to it. @UiField create a variable containing the instance of the element that is manipulatable anywhere in your class.

Comment: This works if the UI is built in GWT, but his question was asking about adding click handlers (and other GWT functionality) to existing HTML on the page. If he was building the whole page in GWT, however, this would definitely be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

One other suggestion - use GQuery.  It makes it easy to attach a simple event listener to the DOM without creating the extra elements that GWT widgets often do:

```
$("id").click(new Function() {
  public boolean f(Event e) {
    Window.alert("This is GWT code without widget baggage!");
    return true;
  }
});
```

See here for more: http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted#Add_an_event_handler

It is a shame there is not more progressive enhancement based GWT code.  IMHO, CSS/HTML do a great job at design/markup - it is just the Javascript I want to replace.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it by setting an event listener.

```
Event.sinkEvents(e, Event.ONCLICK);
Event.setEventListener(e, new EventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
          Window.alert("Clicked!");
     }
});
```